# submit search query if conditions are met

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I go about integrating these two functions together so that when submitting the search form, it will first check the http get response, then depending on whether there was an error or not, either submit the form, or display an error message?

All that I've tried has either made the form not work at all, or not take into account the 'http.get function'.

```
var http = require("http");
var url = 'http://examplepage.com/';

search.submit(function (event) { // submit search query function
        if (searchBox.val().length < 2) {
            searchBox.focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });


http.get(url, function (res) {
            res.resume();
            // successful - so submit search query
        }).on('error', function () {
            // unsuccessful - display error message
        });
```

Comment: I dont get your environment... what's the relation with node.js? You seem to be writing client-side code...?

Comment: I'm setting up a page using node-webkit, with this function I am having the client test the connection to the server before submitting the form.

Comment: Do you want to submit the form through ajax or normal form submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably subscribe on click event for you button that triggers search, the go check the url and inside success handler do

Sample code of Click handler

```
    http.get(url, function (res) { 
         // successful 
         if (searchBox.val().length < 2) {
             $('your form selector').submit();
    }
    }).on('error', function () {
        // unsuccessful - display error message
    });
```